# How can I add const to a decltype(...) typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, decltype

While I have reviewed two similar questions, given this mix of decltypes, references and consts those don't seem to help.

I want to run some tests on two different fields of a structure, `field1` and `field2`.

Some code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

struct my_structure
{
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;
};

std::string calculate_pattern(const std::string& needle)
{
    // Any silly thing instead of the real case
    return needle + ".";
}

template <typename iterator>
bool some_function(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    typedef decltype(*begin) item_type;

    // Can I add more consts? It looks like there are not enough of them!
    std::vector< std::function<std::string& (const item_type &)> > cases;
    cases.emplace_back([](const item_type& a) -> std::string& { return a->field1; });
    cases.emplace_back([](const item_type& a) -> std::string& { return a->field2; });

    /* const */ auto& item = *begin;

    for (const std::function<std::string& (const item_type&)>& fn : cases)
    {
        const auto needle = fn(item); // FAILS: item is const, fn argument is not

        auto result = std::find_if(begin, end, [&fn, &needle](/* const */ auto& a)
          {
             auto pattern = calculate_pattern(needle);
             return fn(a) == pattern;
          }
        );
        
        if (result != end)
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<my_structure> > v(3);
        std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() {
        return std::move(std::make_unique< my_structure>());
        }
    );
    v[0]->field1 = "zz";
    cout << some_function(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as any of the commented `const` is uncommented, the call to `fn` fails, suggesting its argument is not constant.

Don't think too much of the logic (it will always return false), it's simplified from the real code so it can be compiled.

Is there a correct way to mean that the elements in `cases` accept consts? Well, we should start with the vector::value_type. Any other approach? I have tried also putting a const in the typedef, no success.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::remove_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) and [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv)?

Comment: `typedef std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)> item_type;` and you can uncomment comments with const. You want `item_type` to be `unique_ptr` not `unique_ptr&`.

Comment: Great! I tried `std::add_const` but the result was the same (as in `typedef std::add_const<decltype(*begin)>::type item_type`). It _did_ something, because I had to add it also the `for (... : cases)` line.